# Why are my newly added categories not showing up when creating a post?

Tags: categories, posting

When I add a Category, it shows up under the separate "Categories" menu but when I go to create a post, they do not show up under the "Categories" menu on the side for me to check a box and select a category for my new post.

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of the category you added and a screen shot of your categories list when in a post?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.